# How to change the case of same word in entire document in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, replace, case-sensitive

Let's say I have "abc" in multiple places in a file.
g~iw only will only change it "ABC" in just one place (word under the cursor).
But if I want to replace it in entire document, is there a one-line command in vim?

Or do i need to use sed for it?

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_the_word_under_the_cursor

Comment: Read here about substitution: https://vimhelp.org/usr_10.txt.html#10.2

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways of doing this. My prefered method for this specific task would be to [search and replace](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

```
:%s/abc/ABC/g
```

This would replace every occurence in every line of the first string 'abc' with the second string 'ABC'.

(Thank you rampion for pointing out that I had missed selecting the word with '*')
If your cursor is already on the word you want to replace you can press '*' and omit the first string:

```
:%s//ABC/g
```

To make the whole thing more robust, as per Sergio Araujo' comment add boundaries to the search term to prevent false matches that merely include the string

```
:%s/\<abc\>/\U&/g
```

with \U transforming to uppercase and & using the last search to apply it to

Comment: We should use the word boundaries to avoid matching words that are part of the others and a little trick on substitution: `:%s/\<abc\>/\U&/g` . `\U` means uppercase and `&`means last search.

Comment: "if your cursor is already on the word", you can hit `*` to put the word in the pattern register, then use `%s//ABC/g`. Just having your cursor on the word isn't sufficient.